# Python: Creating a List of the First n Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: python, fibonacci

I am new to Python and to these forums.

My question is: How can I create a list of `n` Fibonacci numbers in Python?

So far, I have a function that gives the *`nth`* Fibonacci number, but I want to have a list of the first `n` Fib. numbers for future work.

For example:

```
fib(8) -> [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13]
```

Comment: @JTurk Really, don't say *Thank you* in question.

Comment: i don't follow, can you expound? does this have to do with my edit to the question?

Comment: @JTurk Take a look about [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). We really don't need say *Thank you* . Just accept the correct answer or upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, a recursive implementation that returns a list of numbers by first calculating the list of previous values:

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return [0]
    elif n == 1:
        return [0, 1]
    else:
        lst = fib(n-1)
        lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])
        return lst
```

It works as expected:

```
fib(8)
=> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
```

Comment: This worked very well, thanks! I'll definitely play around with this for a bit to learn how to use this sort of coding practice in future cases!

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way using generators....

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in xrange(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

print list(fib(8)) #prints: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive it use list:

```
def fib(n):
  if n <= 0:
     return []
  if n == 1:
     return [0]
  result = [0, 1]
  if n == 2:
     return result
  for i in xrange(2, n):
     result.append(result[i-1] + result[i-2])
  return result
```