# Anyone knows an easier way to solve this list problem scenario?

Tags: python, list

[So, does anyone know an easier way to solve this problem, or is my way the only correct way to solve this problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZgOE.png)

Comment: Can you make this a [mcve] by posting the code and the intended output as text?

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  It is not acceptable to give us only a link to an off-site question.

Comment: Isn't this a Fibonacci problem?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33325683/python-creating-a-list-of-the-first-n-fibonacci-numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is just another option for computing three elements of the Fibonacci sequence.

**Alternate code to yours**

```
def append_sum(lst):
  for i in range(3):        # Loop 3 times
    lst += [sum(lst[-2:])]  # add sum of last two elements to list
                            # lst[-2:] is last two elements of list
                            # sum(...) is the sum
                            # x += y appends y to x when x and y are lists
  return lst

print(append_sum([1, 1, 2]))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

Comment: Glad I could help. [For loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) are easy.  You may want to add your code to the question rather than the image if possible.